# MYSQLi store result and then get result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function which does the following things

```
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare..
         //check for preparation failure
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param
         //Check for bind error
     mysqli_stmt_execute
         //Check for execution error

     mysqli_stmt_store_result   //Problem is here
         //Check for error
     return $stmt
```

I have these steps in a function because I need it in two placeds the same piece of code. After getting the stmt, I need to check number of rows [`mysqli_Stmt_num_rows`]. So only I have that stored result stmt at the end of the function.

After checking the rows, i need to get a column value from the result. So I tried to execute `mysqli_stmt_get_result` on the returned statement object. It fails.

I just removed the store result part and just returned the executed stmt from the function. Get result works then. But I cannot count rows until I store the result.

Then I have done simple trick that tried to clone the returned statement. Unfortunately, mysqli stmt is not clonable.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you use mysqli_stmt_get_result  immediately after execute?

Comment: " So I tried to execute mysqli_stmt_get_result on the returned statement object" - why did you do that? You already used store_result....

Comment: @Mihai It works if I use immediately after stmt execution before store.

Comment: a) you execute the statement b) you decided whether the result data is transfered in one big step (store_results) _or_ step by step (use_result) and then c) you iterate the data. Once you've decided b) this step is done; no going back there....

Comment: Thanks @VolkerK. How do I find whether returned data is empty or not by using store result?

Comment: As you already said in your question via num_rows. It gives you the number of records that have been tranfered from the server to the client. Since store_result transfers _all_ result records before returning, num_rows should be accurate (...enough to determine =0 or >0 records).

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_result` class also has a property called `num_rows`

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
echo $result->num_rows;
```

If you want to stick to procedural style, which I do not recommend, there is a corresponding function [`mysqli_num_rows($result)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)